# About the BLOB datatype in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, firefox, google-chrome

I have stored an image in MySQL using the BLOB datatype. I am able to
retrieve image through JSP but when I use Chrome or Firefox browser I am
unable to view the image. It is displaying in an encrypted format.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: That datatype is for bloggers onlyyyyyyyyyyy. Do you bloggggg? :)

Comment: Mayby the wrong content-type given to the browser?

Comment: You need to set the content-type.

Comment: ya its BLOB data type!! but when I use Internet Explore it is displaying the image. But where as in chrome and in firefox it is not displaying the image

Comment: but when I use Internet Explore it is displaying the image. It is not working in firefox and chrome only

Comment: i have tried by changing the content type. If there was a mistake in content type then it should not work in IE also. But it works in IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

- Open up Chrome inspector [ ctrl+shift+i ]
- go to the network tab
- clear out the entries
- goto your url
- check the MIME Type in the type column.

This will make sure that your application / server config is sending it as the correct MIME type.